# jtextarea does not pop out

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

```
import net.htmlparser.jericho.*;

@SuppressWarnings({ "serial", "unused" })
public class RenderToText extends JDialog {


    static JTextArea _resultArea = new JTextArea(100, 100);
    JScrollPane scrollingArea = new JScrollPane(_resultArea);
    private final static String newline = "\n";
    int filename = 100;
    String[] fileName = new String[filename];

    public RenderToText(){
        for (int i = 0; i < filename; i++) {
         String fileName = "abc"+i+".txt";
            // A File object to represent the filename
            File f = new File(fileName);
            f.delete();
        }


        _resultArea.setEditable(false);
        //Starting to write files
        try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(
                "C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\FYP\\Link\\abc.txt");
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

        // for each URL, process the URL and render the HTML file
        int numberofURL = 100;
        String[] URL = new String[numberofURL];
        int a;




        // For each URL, assign one text file to store the contents

        // for each URL, extract the URL contents

        for (a = 0; a < numberofURL; a++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberofURL; i++) {

                URL[a] = textReader.readLine();
                try{
                try {
                    try {
                        // Render the text from the HTML file
                        String sourceUrlString = URL[a];


                        System.out.println("Using argument of \""
                                    + sourceUrlString + '"');


                        if (sourceUrlString.indexOf(':') == -1)
                            sourceUrlString = "file:" + sourceUrlString;
                        Source source = new Source(new URL(sourceUrlString));
                        String renderedText = source.getRenderer()
                                .toString();
                        _resultArea.append("\nSimple rendering of the HTML document:\n" + newline);
                        System.out.println(renderedText+ newline);

                        // Write the rendered text to a text file


                        String filename = ("abc" + i + ".txt");
                        Writer output = null;
                        String text = renderedText;
                        File file = new File(filename);
                        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                        output.write(text);
                        output.close();
                        System.out.println("Your file has been written"+ newline);



                        // Count the number of words available in the
                        // rendered text.

                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                new FileReader(
                                        "C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\FYP\\abc"
                                                + i + ".txt"));
                        String line = "", str = "";
                        int count = 0;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            str += line + " ";

                        }
                        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
                        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                            String s = st.nextToken();
                            count++;
                        }
                        _resultArea.append("File has " + count + " words."+ newline);
                    } catch (UnknownServiceException ex) {
                        System.out.println("The following url cannot be processed"+ newline);

                    }

                    System.out.println("\n");
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    System.out.println("\n");
                } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                    System.out.println("End of URL");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }catch(IOException ex){
                System.out.println("The following url cannot be processed due to the need to login");
            }
            }
        }


    }catch (IOException e1) {
    }
    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    content.add(scrollingArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.setContentPane(content);
    this.setTitle("TextAreaDemo B");

    this.pack();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JDialog win = new RenderToText();
        win.setVisible(true);

    }
    }
```

This code extract the contents of a website. I have use append on the output, however the jtextarea does not come out. It cant run, but it **CANT** transfer the output to the jtextarea. What do i missing ?

Comment: Please don't use a `static JTextArea`. I doubt a JTextArea can be incorperated in more that 1 layout at once.

Comment: It also doesn't compile. The imports are not complete.

Comment: You also catch and ignore an IOException. Are you sure that's not causing the problem?

Comment: sorry guys, my internet connection was dropped just now. I am sorry that i have one mistake in my question. It can run but it cant transfer the output into JTextArea. In other words, the JTextArea didnt pop out after finished run. Note that i have append the output to JTextArea.

Answer (score 1):

You are running two loops

```
for (a = 0; a < numberofURL; a++)
    for (int i = 0; i < numberofURL; i++)
```

with 100 steps each. Thus you're reading 10000 URLs from your input file. If there are not enough of them `readline` will return null and thus you'll exceptions (see also comment from extraneon). Get rid of the useless second loop.

Besides the errors in reading the files your textarea should display the output (and it does in my test). Therefore it seems that it lies within your read loop and the exception handling therein.

Note: please also consider the other comments from extraneon.

Comment: hi, i has remove the second loops. However, the JTextArea did not come out after finish run. Where do i missing ? Thanks for you attention.

Comment: Hi jasper, what do you mean by "not come out". Is the window visible, including scrollbars and textarea? You have quite some debug code included. What is written to your console? You may also put in one more line directly where you append to the textarea in order to check that it actually executes this line.

Comment: nope, nothing come out. Just the console run thats all.  Basically this code extracts the contents from a website and display the contents. Before i create the text area, the code can run and display the contents inside the IDE console. However, if i append the normal println to text area, the text area did not come out, but the code run successfully.

Comment: If nothing is printed to the console then either the line FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\FYP\\Link\\abc.txt"); throws a FileNotFoundException or textReader.readLine(); throws an IOException. Both exceptions would be handled by your outermost try-catch. Unfortunately you have an empty catch-block there and thus see not any effect. At least a log statement for the exception should be added here.

Comment: I would like to ask is whether inside the text area has limited space for the contents ?

Comment: The document inside the textarea is basically unlimited. Nevertheless you may run out of resources or performance might degrade if you process really huge amounts of text.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with comment about static JTextArea. If you want to shere content you can use the same Document in two JTextAreas added in different places.